# Backbone underscorejs add value to template

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a simple add event in Backbonejs, I also have template:

```
initialize: function()
{
    this.template = _.template($("#person-template").html());
}

renderperson: function(model)
{
    //model.name is "Jack" for example
    //Now I want to render this template with Name replaced with "Jack"?
    $("#somelement").append( ); //What to do here???
}
```

template is simple:

```
<script type="text/template" id="person-template">
    <div class="person"><%= Name %></div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#somelement").append( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
```

you may also need to add

```
_.bindAll(this)
```

to your initialize method

Comment: 'this.template' is not a function

Comment: did you add _.bindAll(this) to the initialize function?

Comment: Oh I didn't added it to initialize function I added it in render person. Now it works. Sorry and thanks !:)

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you:
http://backbonejs.org/#View-render

```
var Bookmark = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```